# How do I test whether interclass variability is significantly larger than intraclass variability?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

I am doing human activity type classification (classifying activities such as sitting, walking, and riding a bike). The data is collected from 12 different participants and each activity type from each participant has a different sample size. There exist certain intraclass variabilities. How do I statistically test whether the interclass variability is more significant than intraclass variability? Cheers!

Intraclass variability is the variability among different participants but within the same activity type.

Interclass variability is the variability among different activity types.

The data are like:

```
                 Activity A                    Activity B
```

participant 1:   thousands of samples(1.A)    thousands of samples(1.B)

participant 2:   thousands of samples(2.A)     thousands of samples(2.B)

participant 3:   thousands of samples(3.A)     thousands of samples(3.B)

participant 4:   thousands of samples(4.A)     thousands of samples(4.B)

The samples are sliding-window-based statistical features (mean, std, IQR, etc) from a head-mounted gyroscope to track head movement.

When I did t-test on each pair from (1.A) (2.A) (3.A) (4.A), they showed statistical significance (p<0.05) as intraclass variability. When I did a t-test on activity A and activity B, they were also statistically significant as interclass variability. How do I show whether the variation between activity A and activity B overwhelms the variation between participants, so that activity type instead of participant dominates the data distribution?

Comment: Can you clarify a) do you have several observations per participant for each activity, b) what do the observations for each activity represent (e.g. minutes spent doing the activity per day? something else?) and c) do you want to know the variance attributable to participants, activities, or both? (or some combination of the two?)

Comment: @Sointu a) yes, each activity happens at least 10 times for each of the participants. b) the observations are the statistical features (sliding-windows-based mean, std, etc) of acceleration data collected from a head-mounted gyroscope. c) I am selecting important features whose interclass variability is much more significant than intraclass variability, to show they are useful features.

Comment: @Sointu a) Since the data to analyze are sliding-window-based, each occurrence of activity lasts for hundreds of sliding windows, so there are thousands of samples per activity per participant.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. I wrote my below answer before the last edit to the question, now I don't know if it's relevant at all, but I'll leave it up in case it has some relevance.

Original answer:

One way to do this is to run a multilevel regression model with just the random effect of activity and compute the intraclass correlation. E.g. in R lmer

```
model<-lmer(outcome ~ (1|activity_type), data=data)
performance::icc(model)
```

This will give you the proportion of variance in your outcome attributable to differences between your activities. You can for instance use

```
confint(model)
```

to see whether the amount of activity variance is different from zero using confidence intervals.

You can also put in both random intercept of activity and participant

```
model2<-lmer(outcome ~ (1|activity_type) + (1|participant_id), data=data)
performance::icc(model2, by_group = T)
```

to see both participant and activity type variance proportions (as well as the residual variance, which would be the remaining proportion).

To get a p-value for the significance of the activity-related variance component, I've seen it suggested that you can run the same model as single-level model

```
model<-lmer(outcome ~ (1|participant_id), data=data, REML=F) #you need to use ML estimation for model comparisons
model_lm<-lm(outcome ~ 1, data=data)
#and then compare the two models
anova(model, model_lm)
```

and the resulting p-value would indicate whether the activity variance component is significant (though admittedly I'm not entirely sure is it's OK to compare a single-level model and a multilevel model like this).

Edited to add: I rarely deal with as large datasets as yours, so it may well be that there is some better way considering the number of observations.